# Flutter deserialisation using generics error

Tags: flutter, deserialization

I am trying to deserialise and serialise a generic class in flutter using build_runner. The code I have written is as below:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'api_response_message_model.dart';

part 'api_response_base_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ApiResponseBaseModel<T> {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _dataFromJson, toJson: _dataToJson)
  T data;
  ApiResponseMessageModel message;

  ApiResponseBaseModel({this.data, this.message});

  factory ApiResponseBaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ApiResponseBaseModelFromJson(json);

  T _dataFromJson<T>(Map<String, dynamic> input) =>
      input['value'] as T;

  Map<String, dynamic> _dataToJson<T>(T input) =>
      {'value': input};
}
```

I am getting the error as below when running command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `data`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
package:premier_app/models/api_response_base_model.dart:10:5
  ╷
10│   T data;
  │     ^^^^
  ╵
```

Please help me identify the problem and know the correct solution.

I also did tried the method mentioned here but no luck in removing the error - https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/7b40e9b04805bf921e4cebb87ec4ad7b8e1a2d29/json_serializable/test/generic_files/generic_class.dart#L20-L21

Comment: Please share your `_dataFromJson` & `_dataToJson` methods.

Comment: Added them in the code above. Please check.

Comment: The methods should be defined outside the class `ApiResponseBaseModel<T>`,  isn't it? Should not be members of the class.

Comment: Moving it outside should get it working

Comment: I did as you suggested. But still the same error

Comment: Can you please give me a snippet of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209538/discussion-between-vibhor-goyal-and-hemanth-raj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please move the `_dataFromJson` & `_dataToJson` methods outside the scope of class `ApiResponseBaseModel<T>`.

Example:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'api_response_message_model.dart';

part 'api_response_base_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ApiResponseBaseModel<T> {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _dataFromJson, toJson: _dataToJson)
  T data;
  ApiResponseMessageModel message;

  ApiResponseBaseModel({this.data, this.message});

  factory ApiResponseBaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ApiResponseBaseModelFromJson(json);
}

T _dataFromJson<T>(Map<String, dynamic> input) =>
    input['value'] as T;

Map<String, dynamic> _dataToJson<T>(T input) =>
    {'value': input};
```

I did try out myself, works!
Generated methods look like:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'api_response_base_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

ApiResponseBaseModel<T> _$ApiResponseBaseModelFromJson<T>(
    Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return ApiResponseBaseModel<T>(
    data: _dataFromJson(json['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    message: json['message'],
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ApiResponseBaseModelToJson<T>(
        ApiResponseBaseModel<T> instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'data': _dataToJson(instance.data),
      'message': instance.message,
    };
```